# How to write unit test for Guava rate Limiter applied on a methods

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, guava, junit5, junit-jupiter

I am trying to write unit test for RateLimiter using guava.

Below is my service class where I have added RateLimiter. I wanted to rate Limit method-xyzMethod present in service class. I have made qps/tps as 3 for rateLimiter.

Can anyone help me to write unit test to check RateLimiter working or not for

1. any single method
2. multiple methods.

```
@Service
class Service2 {
    private  RateLimiter rateLimiter;

    @Autowired
    public void setRateLimiter(RateLimiter rateLimiter) {
        this.rateLimiter = rateLimiter;
    }

    public method1(){

        rateLimiter.acquire();
        System.out.println(new Date() + ": Beep");
        xyzMethod();

    }

    public method2(){

        rateLimiter.acquire();
        System.out.println(new Date() + ": Beep");
        xyzMethod();

    }

    public method3(){

        rateLimiter.acquire();
        System.out.println(new Date() + ": Beep");
        xyzMethod();

    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class RatelimiterConfig {

  @Value("${tps}")
  private int tps;

  @Bean
  public RateLimiter rateLimiter(){
    return  RateLimiter.create(tps);
  }
}
```